# how to decrease memory with nodejs, socketio, redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am trying to use NodeJS with Socket.io.

When I try, each socket connection increase the the NodeJS memory usage but does not decrease when clients disconnect. I know this has been brought up since years ago.

However with clustering using Redis, each socket connection will take up memory in Redis, and I believe the same issue where memory usage will not decrease even when clients disconnect.

How can I manage the Redis memory?

EDIT: It does not appear to be what I expected. I just tried with latest Socket.io, NodeJS, socket.io-redis. Each connection STILL takes up memory in NodeJS server, but no in Redis. I guess the question would be how to manage server memory, besides waiting for gc to kick in.

Comment: `socket.io` should raise a `disconnect` event, hook into that and expire the key in Redis.

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible. NodeJS or Socket.io make use of Redis for clustering. The keys are blackboxed right?

Comment: the term “black box” doesn’t exist with open source code :) I believe the key looks something like `socket-<id>` but best checking the source (or even Redis).